Automata reaching the same state when reading the same word long enough
Suppose there is a deterministic finite automaton (DFA) $A$ for which there is a $k>0$ such that, for all words $w$ longer than $k$, there is a state $q_w$ such that reading $w$ starting from any other state of $A$ will reach $q_w$.
In other words, the "effect" of reading $w$ is the same no matter the prefix, but only if $w$ is long enough.
Is there a standard name for automata of this kind and what is known about them?
Edit: clarified that there is one state for each long-enough word and not a single state for all the long words.

I don't have any references to point you towards for this kind of automaton, but I can tell you exactly what languages can be recognized by this type of automaton.
An automaton of this form must accept a language of the form $(\Sigma^*\cdot X) \cup Y$, where $X$ is a finite set of strings of the same length $k$, and $Y$ is a finite set of strings each of length less than $k$. In other words, for strings of length at least $k$, the automaton must accept exactly those strings that end in a string in $X$, while for strings of length at most $k$, the automaton must accept exactly those strings in $Y$.
On the other hand, if we have a set $X$ of strings of the same length $k$, and another set $Y$ of strings each of length less than $k$, then we can construct an automaton matching your constraints that accepts exactly the language $(\Sigma^*\cdot X) \cup Y$.
proofs
Let's prove these two claims one at a time. First, consider an automaton $A$ of your form with an associated value of $k$. Let $Y$ be the set of strings of length less than $k$ that are accepted by $A$. And let $X$ be the set of strings $w$ of length exactly $k$ such that $q_w$ is an accepting state. I claim that the language of the automaton $L(A)$ is then $(\Sigma^*\cdot X) \cup Y$. To prove this, we can consider four cases by splitting all strings into those accepted by the automaton and not and also those of length less than $k$ and not:

If $w$ is a string of length less than $k$ and is in $L(A)$, then by definition of $Y$, $w$ is in $Y$, and so $w$ is also in $(\Sigma^*\cdot X) \cup Y$.
If $w$ is a string of length less than $k$ and is not in $L(A)$, then by definition of $Y$, $w$ is not in $Y$. Also, $(\Sigma^*\cdot X)$ contains only strings of length at least $k$, so $w$ is also not in $(\Sigma^*\cdot X)$. As a result, $w$ is not in $(\Sigma^*\cdot X) \cup Y$.
If $w$ is a string of length at least $k$ and is in $L(A)$, then let $w'$ be the suffix of $w$ of length $k$. We know that no matter the start state, running $A$ on input $w'$ will lead to state $q_{w'}$. Therefore, running $A$ on $w$ must end at state $q_{w'}$, since the last $k$ steps of that execution are exactly the process of running $A$ on $w'$ from some starting state. Since $A$ accepts $w$, we can conclude that $q_{w'}$ is an accepting state. Therefore, $w'$ must be in $X$ (by the definition of $X$), and so $w$ must be in $(\Sigma^*\cdot X)$. As a result, we see that $w$ is in $(\Sigma^*\cdot X) \cup Y$.
If $w$ is a string of length at least $k$ and is not in $L(A)$, then let $w'$ be the suffix of $w$ of length $k$ just like in the previous case. As before, running $A$ on $w$ must end at state $q_{w'}$, so since $A$ rejects $w$, we can conclude that $q_{w'}$ is not an accepting state. Therefore, $w'$ must not be in $X$ (by the definition of $X$), and so $w$ must not be in $(\Sigma^*\cdot X)$. We also know that $w$ is not in $Y$ since $w$ has length at least $k$, while strings in $Y$ have length less than $k$. Putting this together, we see that $w$ is not in $(\Sigma^*\cdot X) \cup Y$.

All of this casework has shown that a string $w$ is in $(\Sigma^*\cdot X) \cup Y$ exactly when it is in $L(A)$, and therefore that $L(A)=(\Sigma^*\cdot X) \cup Y$.
Now, suppose we have a set $X$ of strings of the same length $k$, and another set $Y$ of strings each of length less than $k$. We will construct an automaton matching your constraints that accepts exactly the language $(\Sigma^*\cdot X) \cup Y$. This automaton will contain a state for every string of length at most $k$, and the transitions will be such that at all times, the state is the longest suffix of the input so far of length $\le k$. This means the DFA will start at the empty string state, on input $x$, a state $w$ with $|w| < k$ will transition to state $wx$, and on input $x$, a state $aw$ with $|a|=1$ and $|w| = k-1$ will transition to the state $wx$. Finally, the accept states of this DFA will be exactly the strings in $X$ and $Y$.
It's pretty straightforward to see that the constructed DFA has language $(\Sigma^*\cdot X) \cup Y$. It is also an automaton matching your constraints since for every $w$ of length at least $k$, if you let $w'$ be the length $k$ suffix of $w$, running the automaton on $w$ from any state will put the DFA into state $w'$. In other words, $q_w=w'$.

This looks correct to me. Very nice!

Another characterization is that a DFA such that all states are reachable has the property in the OP iff it is a quotient of an automaton on $\Sigma^{\le k}$ described in the penultimate paragraph.

That’s really nice! Then I think I’ll need a weaker hypothesis for what I’m doing. Thanks!

Adding to Mikhail Rudoy's very good answer: the languages of the form $\Sigma^*\cdot X \cup Y$ are known under the name definite languages (resp. definite events in the lingo of the 1960s). The following paper contains a nice diagram comparing the definite languages to many other "subregular" language classes:

Henning Bordihn, Markus Holzer, Martin Kutrib: Determination of finite automata accepting subregular languages, Theoretical Computer Science 410(35), 2009, pp. 3209-3222.

As mentioned in that paper, the early automata theory literature features quite a few results concerning definite languages and related classes:

M. Perles, M. O. Rabin and E. Shamir: The theory of definite automata, IEEE Trans. Comput. EC-12 (1963), pp. 233–243
J. A. Brzozowski: Canonical regular expressions and minimal state graphs for definite events, in: J. Fox (Ed.), Mathematical Theory of Automata, in: MRI
Symposia Series, vol. 12, Polytechnic Press of the Polytechnic Institute of Brooklyn, Brooklyn, NY, 1963, pp. 529–561.
A. Ginzburg: About some properties of definite, reverse-definite and related automata, IEEE Trans. Comput. EC-15 (5) (1966), pp. 806–810
Paz, A., Peleg, B. : Ultimate-definite and symmetric-definite events and automata, J. ACM 12 (1965), pp. 399–410


Wow these references are super interesting!

This is very reminiscent of synchronizing words. However in your case all words of length more than $k$ are synchronizing.

That's a useful pointer!

Such an automaton is called k–determined.
It is very closely related to foldings of de Bruijn graphs.

Edit: following an edit to the question, what follows is not correct -- it assumes that the state reached is the same for all words.
I think that the automata that obey your condition recognize precisely the languages that are either finite or cofinite.
For one direction, let $A$ be such an automaton. We know that, for any word $w$ with $|w|>n$, reading $w$ leads us to one state $q$. Hence, the language of $A$ is finite if $q$ is not accepting (only words of length $\leq n$ can be accepted, hence finitely many), and cofinite if $q$ is accepting (only words of length $\leq n$ can be rejected, hence finitely many).
Conversely, let $L$ be a finite language, letting $n$ be greater than the length of the longest word of $L$, we can build a DFA for $L$ where any word longer than $n$ gets mapped to a rejecting sink state. A similar argument works for cofinite languages $L$: letting $n$ be greater than the length of the longest word which is not in $L$, we can build a DFA for $L$ where any word longer than $n$ gets mapped to an accepting sink state. (In fact, for $L$ finite or cofinite, your property will in particular be obeyed by the minimal DFA for $L$.)

I'm sorry, I think the question was ambigue. What I meant is that for each word long enough there is a state where you end up when you read the same word, not that the state is the same for all long words. I'll edit the question.
